# Java HashSet contains function not working

Tags: java, hash, hashcode, hashset

I am writing a simple program as follow: Given two numbers M and N, p is from [M,N] and q is from [1,p-1], find all irreducible fractions of p/q.
My idea is brute force all possible value of p, q. And using HashSet to avoid duplicated fraction. However, somehow the contains function not working as expected.

My code

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Fraction {
    private int p;
    private int q;

    Fraction(int p, int q) {
        this.p = p;
        this.q = q;
    }

    public static int getGCD(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0)
            return a;
        else 
            return getGCD(b, a % b);
    }

    public static Fraction reduce(Fraction f) {
        int c = getGCD(f.p, f.q);
        return new Fraction(f.p / c, f.q / c);
    }

    public static HashSet<Fraction> getAll(int m, int n) {
        HashSet<Fraction> res = new HashSet<Fraction>();
        for (int p = m; p <= n; p++)
            for (int q = 1; q < p; q++) {
                Fraction f = new Fraction(p,q);
                Fraction fr = reduce(f);
                if (!res.contains(fr))
                    res.add(fr);
            }
        return res;
    }

    public static void print(Fraction f) {
        System.out.println(f.p + "/" + f.q);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashSet<Fraction> res = getAll(2, 4);
        for (Fraction f : res)
            print(f);
    }

}
```

Here is the output of program

```
4/3
3/1
4/1
2/1
3/2
2/1
```

you can see the fraction 2/1 is duplicated. Anyone can help me figure out why and how to fix it.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override the `Object#equals` and `Object#hashCode` methods in the `Fraction` class. These methods are used by `HashSet` to determine if two objects are the same. When you don't override them, the equals method tests equality of the objects' references rather that equality of their field values.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + p;
    result = prime * result + q;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Fraction other = (Fraction) obj;
    if (p != other.p)
        return false;
    if (q != other.q)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I only wanted to add that these functions can be usually implemented automatically by your IDE and you don't need to code them. Unless you want to have a specific behaviour, the one provided by the IDE are usually enough for most cases.

Comment: @ordago, true, the above implementation was automatically generated by Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `Fraction#equals()` and `Fraction#hashcode()`, because that is used for determining weather the set contains certain value or not. Without it, object references are compared, which will not give you the desired result.

Comment: Lets not forget about `hashCode()` method as well: [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Fraction` class does not override `hashCode` and `equals`. A `HashMap` contains tries to find a key with the same hashCode (and equals) as the one you provided. As you create a new instance of `Fraction`, it will never be the same as the one already in the `HashMap`. Here is how you would do `hashCode` and `equals`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode() + p * 24 + q * 24;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof Fraction)) return false;
    return ((Fraction) other).p == this.p && ((Fraction) other).q == this.q;
}
```